# Is EFE harder to solve when I convert everything into scalars

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace

[EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) is written as:

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu \nu}.$$

I have learned that one of Einstein's mistakes was to neglect the second term on the LHS:

$$R_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu \nu}.$$

Which is false because taking the divergence leads to a contradiction. I've always wondered why did Einstein refer to this equation rather than the scalar form:

$$R=\kappa T$$

Which is simpler and can be derived from the original form then multiplying by the inverse metric tensor:

$$g^{\mu\nu}(R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu})=g^{\mu \nu}\kappa T_{\mu \nu}$$
$$R-\frac{1}{2}4R=\kappa T$$
$$R-2R=\kappa T$$
$$-R=\kappa T.$$

then absorbing the minus sign into the constant. Is solving the equation harder in this form? It seems much neater and simpler in case it's easier.

Comment: Are you aware that your last line is one equation, while the first line actually is a shorthand version of writing $D^2$ equations (so in $D=4$ these are 16 equations)?

Comment: What you've ended up with is [Nordstrom's field equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordstr%C3%B6m%27s_theory_of_gravitation). This was one of the early attempts at a metric theory of gravity, but it doesn't match experiment so it failed.

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't think so, it's just contraction of EFE with metric, and there are no assumptions made about the form of R (or metric tensor)

Comment: Have you tried running the derivation in reverse? Starting from $R = \kappa T$ can you get the full equation? surely not. The simpler equation is a necessary but not a sufficient condition.

Comment: So you made 16 equations into one. You just lost information that the full EFEs gave you in the first place, and therefore, its predictive power in experiments.

Comment: There is something known as Newman-Penrose formalism, where you transform Einstein's equations and Bianchi identities into a set of differential equations involving only complex scalar functions. You can look it up

Comment: @JohnRennie Nordstrom's theory would also include the condition that the Weyl tensor vanishes, which the OP is not assuming. (Of course as others have pointed out all the OP has done is project Einstein's equations down to a single equation, but the result isn't Nordstrom's theory).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact is that the tensorial Einstein equation has 10 independent components in four dimensions, while the scalar equation is a one-component equation.
If the Einstein equation you wrote holds then the scalar equation is true in principle since the Einstein equation implies that  $R=-\kappa T$.
If $R=-\kappa T$ then this does not imply that the Einstein equation holds (in some cases that come to my mind the scalar equation can be solved and then the Einstein equation will fix the integration constants that appeared when solving the scalar equation). However,the Einstein equation contains more information about the gravitational field than the scalar equation.

EDIT:

Let me elaborate further with an example. Consider that the energy momentum tensor is the one derived from the Maxwell Lagrangian. In this case, the physical system is described by the Einstein-Maxwell system (1)

\begin{eqnarray}
&&G_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}~,\\
&&T_{\mu\nu} = F_{\mu\xi}F^{\nu}_{~\xi} - \frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}F_{\xi\sigma}F^{\xi\sigma}~,\\
&&F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}- \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}~,\\
&&A_{\mu} = \left(\mathcal{A}(r),0,0,0\right)~,\\
&&\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=0
\end{eqnarray}

where i considered only radial electric fields for simplicity. One can proove now, that in four dimensions, the Maxwell energy momentum tensos is traceless. Hence from Einstein equation one obtains
$$R=0.$$ Now this is a one component equation. We have to impose a particular form for the spacetime to solve this (an ansatz). The most general static and spherically symmetric ansatz is given by (see [Blau notes (sections 24,30)](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf), or pretty  much any GR textbook)

\begin{equation} ds^{2} = -g_{tt}(r)dt^2 + g_{rr}(r)dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta ^2 + sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}) (2).\end{equation}

Now plugging this expression in $R=0$ one can obtain a single second order differential equation for the unknown functions $g_{rr}(r),g_{tt}(r)$. As one can see this is not progress. We cannot solve the full system by using only $R=0$. We can further constrain the system by imposing that

$$g_{tt}=b(r) = 1/g_{rr}$$

At the moment there is no reason to do so, except maybe from the fact that Schwarzchild's black hole satisfies this condition, or if we're aware of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3222), but in this case, we obtain a second order differential equation from $R=0$. It is just

$$R =  -\frac{r^2 b''(r)+4 r b'(r)+2 b(r)-2}{r^2} =0$$

which we can solve easily

$$b(r) = 1 +\frac{c_1}{r} + \frac{c_2}{r^2}.$$

Now we have to substitute this metric in the full Einstein equations and the maxwell equation to find that

$$b(r) = 1 -\frac{2M}{r} + \frac{Q^2}{r^2}~, \mathcal{A}(r)=Q/r$$

where $M,Q$ are the mass and electric charge of the black hole [section (30)](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf). This is the [Reissner-Nordstrom black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric).

This is indeed the solution of the field equations. However we made an assumption that $g_{tt}=1/g_{rr}$ and we eventually ended up using Einstein equations to solve the system.

Let us now ignore the $R=0$ equation and consider the full Einstein equation under the general metric ansatz (2). Plugging everything in the Einstein equation from the $tt,rr$ components of the equation we find that

$$g_{tt}=1/g_{rr}~,$$

without assuming anything. Now one can solve the Maxwell equation and eventually the $\theta\theta$ component of the Einstein equation to obtain the same solution. So, one can obtain the same solution with both proccedures but using the scalar equation just requires more calculations. From my experience however, sometimes using the scalar equation after assuming $g_{tt}g_{rr}=1$ is the way to go because of the complexity of the system, but this is rarely encountered in the standard cases.

Finally, from a field theory point of view, the action for the above system is

$$S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{R}{2} - \frac{1}{4}F_{\xi\sigma}F^{\xi\sigma}\right)$$

By variation with respect to the fields, the field equations are the system (1). Hence, in any case, the equations to be solved are the Einstein and Maxwell equations, not the scalar equation. The only use of the scalar equation would be to write the Einstein equation as
$$R_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}~.$$

Therefore, the scalar equation acts as a kind of constraint to solve the system, but in any case the system is described by the Einstein equation.

Answer (score 0):

Ricci tensor $R_{\mu}^{\nu}$ can decomposed into deviatoric (trace-free) and "hydrostatic" (deviatoric-free) tensor which are orthogonal to each other (see ref. [1]). It is $$R_{\mu}^{\nu}= R_{\mu}^{\nu}-1/4~{tr}(R_{\mu}^{\nu})~\delta_{\mu}^{\nu}+1/4~ tr(R_{\mu}^{\nu})~\delta_{\mu}^{\nu}~\equiv~ dev(R_{\mu}^{\nu})+1/4~ R~\delta_{\mu}^{\nu}~.\tag{1}$$

The expression (1) inserted in Einstein field equations results in two independent equations: $$dev(R_{\mu}^{\nu})=\kappa~ dev(T_{\mu}^{\nu})~, \tag{2} $$ $$-R=\kappa~ T ~.\tag{3} $$ The assumption that gravitation is described only by equation (3) means that all 6 components of deviatoric tensors (Ricci, as well as stress-energy) must be identically zero, as it happens in case of conformaly Minkowski's metric (Nordström solution) $$g_{\mu\nu}\equiv exp(\phi)~\eta_{\mu\nu} \tag{4}$$
However, because Maxwell equations are independent of conformal transformations the Nordström theory was not able to describe the observed bending of light rays in gravitation field.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature